# Store $('body, html') selection as jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, variables, jquery-selectors

I'm optimizing the JS code, and stumbled over this question:
At various places in the scripts there are jQuery selectors which select 'body, html', mostly to change/check-for a class. Now I was thinking, if it would increase the performance if I'd store the selection in a variable, or will it be the opposite and the large elements will decrease the performance of the site.

Comment: Did you actually profile your site and determine this was an issue? Also, I strongly recommend against using global variables like this (storing classes and then polling for them) except for immutable state (like modernizr does).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have to admit, no, i didn´t profile it. It was more a general question out of curiosity. To your second point: Most of the time I have to set the overflow value of the body, or scroll to a certain position - so theres no other way to do it. Or?

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Doubtful it would make any significant difference unless the selectors were inside a rapidly firing event handler like `scroll`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, caching selectors is a known optimisation technique in jQuery and means you will have to make a query one less time. So it will undoubtedly be faster since it will not have to query the DOM every time.

That said - Unless you are querying it thousands of times each second, just querying `html, body` will not have any noticeable performance impact. I would focus optimisation time elsewhere although in general it is considered good practice to cache DOM selections for a simpler programmer mental model (less strings to get typos in).